# Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')

Tags: spreadsheet, sourceforge-appscript

i have this error in spreadsheetsand appscript

Hello, good day, I am having this problem in spreadsheets, when using app script, I get the error when debugging or running my code "Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')"
I was researching but I am a student and new to this platform, I would ask you to please support me, thank you!
[spreadsheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZShR.png)
[appscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpHCT.png)

code

```
// Guardar celdas

function Guardar(){
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ENERO2024 = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("ENERO2024"); // Nombre de hoja del formulario
  var datos = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Datos"); // Nombre de hoja donde se almacenan datos

  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[ENERO2024.getRange("B2:E2").getValue(),//FECHA
                  ENERO2024.getRange("B3:E3").getValue(),//VENDEDOR
                  ENERO2024.getRange("B4:E4").getValue(),//H ENTRADA
                  ENERO2024.getRange("B5:E5").getValue(),//H SALIDA 
                  ENERO2024.getRange("D14").getValue(),//HELADOS VENDIDOS
                  ENERO2024.getRange("B16:B17").getValue(),//PACA
                  ENERO2024.getRange("D7").getValue(),//FRESA
                  ENERO2024.getRange("D8").getValue(),//CAJETA
                  ENERO2024.getRange("D9").getValue(),//OBLEA
                  ENERO2024.getRange("D10").getValue(),//OREO
                  ENERO2024.getRange("D11").getValue(),//GALLETA
                  ENERO2024.getRange("D12").getValue(),//V.GRANDE
                  ENERO2024.getRange("D13").getValue(),//V.CHICO
                  ENERO2024.getRange("D16:D17").getValue(),//DINERO TOTAL
                  ENERO2024.getRange("E16:E17").getValue()]] ;

// Inyección de datos a hoja donde se almacenan datos
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,15).setValues(valores); 

  }
```

Comment: It means `datos` is `null` which, in turn, means that `hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Datos")` returned `null`. `getSheetByName` returns `null` when it can't find the sheet you asked for. Are you sure there's a sheet named "Datos"?

Comment: hi ouroborus, I saw that it had a capital letter ("Datos") on line 6 of the code, but I modified it to ("datos") and it still gives me the error on the last line. but if I have a sheet called "datos" in spreadsheets